# Are the subnets of a Class C network Class C networks themselves?

Tags: networking, subnet

Example. if i have a Class C network 205.67.35.0 and i create subnets borrowing 3 host bits so the mask is 255.255.255.224 /27. Are these resulting subnets Class C networks too or just a custom network?

Comment: Please note that class full networks on the internet have been replaced with CIDR since 1993. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question can be interpreted in two ways:

#### 1. If you're stuck in 1990's, and "Class C" is determined by leading bits

**No.** Although Class C was determined by the `1 1 0` leading bits (and 209 indeed starts with those bits), it was *defined* as having 3 bits for type + 21 bits for network. [RFC 950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc950), which introduced subnetting, had a clear separation between "networks" and "subnets":

```
      For example, the Internet address might be interpreted as:

         <network-number><subnet-number><host-number>

      [...]

      For example, on a Class B network with a 6-bit wide subnet field,
      an address would be broken down like this:

                           1                   2                   3
       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
      +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
      |1 0|        NETWORK            |  SUBNET   |    Host Number    |
      +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Later on:

```
   Network Number

      The network field of the Internet address.

   Subnet

      One or more physical networks forming a subset of an Internet
      network.  A subnet is explicitly identified in the Internet
      address.

   [...]

   Subnet Number

      A number identifying a subnet within a network.
```

Therefore a subnet was not a network, and your "/27" was not a Class-C network by itself; it was a 3-bit-wide *subnet* of one.

#### 2. If you're in 2017, and by "Class C" you actually mean /24 (255.255.255.0)

Still **no,** because the /27 subnetwork has an obviously different netmask from what people usually call "Class C".

On the bright side, since classless routing no longer imposes specific network lengths, the /27 is no longer a mere *subnet* – it's as much a 'network' as a /24 is.

---

*And in the name of all that's routable, [please stop using address classes.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4632)*

Answer (score 0):

Yes the networks are still a class C:

```
Address:   205.67.35.0           11001101.01000011.00100011.000 00000
Netmask:   255.255.255.224 = 27  11111111.11111111.11111111.111 00000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.31              00000000.00000000.00000000.000 11111
=>
Network:   205.67.35.0/27        11001101.01000011.00100011.000 00000 (Class C)
Broadcast: 205.67.35.31          11001101.01000011.00100011.000 11111
HostMin:   205.67.35.1           11001101.01000011.00100011.000 00001
HostMax:   205.67.35.30          11001101.01000011.00100011.000 11110
Hosts/Net: 30

Address:   205.67.35.32          11001101.01000011.00100011.001 00000
Netmask:   255.255.255.224 = 27  11111111.11111111.11111111.111 00000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.31              00000000.00000000.00000000.000 11111
=>
Network:   205.67.35.32/27       11001101.01000011.00100011.001 00000 (Class C)
Broadcast: 205.67.35.63          11001101.01000011.00100011.001 11111
HostMin:   205.67.35.33          11001101.01000011.00100011.001 00001
HostMax:   205.67.35.62          11001101.01000011.00100011.001 11110
Hosts/Net: 30   

Address:   205.67.35.64          11001101.01000011.00100011.010 00000
Netmask:   255.255.255.224 = 27  11111111.11111111.11111111.111 00000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.31              00000000.00000000.00000000.000 11111
=>
Network:   205.67.35.64/27       11001101.01000011.00100011.010 00000 (Class C)
Broadcast: 205.67.35.95          11001101.01000011.00100011.010 11111
HostMin:   205.67.35.65          11001101.01000011.00100011.010 00001
HostMax:   205.67.35.94          11001101.01000011.00100011.010 11110
Hosts/Net: 30
```

Comment: Sorry, this is just wrong.  A Class C is a /24.  While the sub netted networks are valid, they are not a Class C.

Comment: lol yes they are! You can't change fact. Yes as grawity nicely wrote in the other answer, today we're referring to subnetting, but this is still a Class C.

Comment: Look at http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPAddressClassABandCNetworkandHostCapacities.htm or any decent resource. A class C has always comprised of 254 hosts - the difference between classful and classless is that in classful the range implied by the first octet implied the size of the network, which no longer applies. I used to build ISPs for a living. (Including buying and selling of IP space). What are your qualification?